# How to setup flutter app in vscode in Ubuntu and set up emulator?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

How to use flutter in VS Code in Ubuntu with emulator.
I am not able to connect to flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think you should use Android studio it is better than Visual Studio Code and if you want to get started, here is the link of installing android studio and flutter on ubuntu.
[How To Install And Setup Flutter On Ubuntu 18.04.1](https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-flutter-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-bionic-beaver/)

Answer (score 0):

You could always install Android Studio just to create some emulators (kinda overkill). Or you can use android emulators like Genymotion